# DotNetNuke module uninstall error

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

Every time I uninstall a DotNetNuke module and check the box to remove files, it completely kills my site.

I'm running IIS7 on the x86 Windows 7 beta, and have had this problem with both 4.8.4 and 4.9.2.  When the error happens, if I replace all of the DLL files in the bin folder, the site comes back to life.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this?

The error I get is as follows...

Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'IClientAPICallbackEventHandler' is not defined.

Source Error:

Line 41:     ''' -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Line 42:     Partial Class DefaultPage
Line 43:         Inherits DotNetNuke.Framework.CDefault : Implements IClientAPICallbackEventHandler
Line 44: 
Line 45: #Region "Properties"

Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Default.aspx.vb    Line: 43

EDIT:
The files that get removed from the /bin folder during the uninstall of a module are:
DotNetNuke.Services.Syndication.dll
DotNetNuke.WebControls.dll
DotNetNuke.WebUtility.dll
SharpZipLib.dll

I'm not directly referencing any of those files - so am guessing that it must be a bug of some sort in the uninstall process.  These files get removed during the uninstall only if my "Copy Local" setting is "True" on my DotNetNuke.dll reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you maybe compiling against a different version of one of the DNN dlls, and have that reference set to Copy Local?

Comment: my references to the DotNetNuke.dll file are set to copy local.  that should probably always be set to false, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yeah, I would suggest always making sure that DotNetNuke dlls are not Copy Local.  For some other dlls (like for component libraries) it may make sense to use Copy Local.